# Norm of linear operator -- verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This problem seems a bit too easy, so I wanted my answer to be checked.

Question:

> Let $\Lambda:C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ such that $\Lambda f=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ for all $f\in C[a,b]$. Let $\|f\|=^{\ \max}_{a\leq t\leq b}\|f(t)\|.$ Find $\|\Lambda\|$.

My attempt:

Let $f\in C[a,b]$ satisfy $\|f\|=1$. Then $f(t)\leq1$ for all $t\in[a,b]$. Now,

$$
\Lambda f=\int_a^xf(t)dt\leq\int_a^xdt=x-a,
$$
and the equality holds if $f(t)=1$ for all $t\in[a,b]$. Thus,

$$
\|\Lambda\|:=\sup\{\|\Lambda f\|:f\in C[a,b]\wedge \|f\|=1\}=x-a.
$$

Am I missing something, or is it just a simple exercise?

Comment: You've written $x$ instead of $b$ in a couple of places but apart from that, this is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer doesn't make sense as written, but has some good steps.  What is $x$?  Be careful to keep track of $x$ as an input from your domain, over which you take the maximum when computing the norm.  Even in the definition it should say $(\Lambda f)(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$; it is giving the value at a particular $x$.

It is correct that if $\|f\|\leq 1$, then $|(\Lambda f)(x)|\leq x-a\leq b-a$, which implies that $\|\Lambda f\|\leq b-a$, hence $\|\Lambda\|\leq b-a$.  With $f\equiv 1$ you get $\|\Lambda f\|=b-a$, yielding the other direction in the equality $\|\Lambda\|=b-a$.

Comment: Of course, $f$ depends on $x$, and not $t$! I knew something was off. Thanks!